# Why docker push only working when tag of pulled image is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, gcloud

I am using gcloud for deploying and I noticed a behaviour and I am not able to understand why is it happening.

Suppose there exists a docker image `xyz` so the first thing I do is I pull `xyz` and it works as expected.

Then I put a tag to it by `docker tag redis gcr.io/project-name/redis`

Now comes the doubt i.e.., I am am doing docker push in this way -->

`gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/practice-192718/redis`

Then it's working

else if I do in this way -->

`gcloud docker -- push redis`

It don't works.

Can you please clear this doubt of me? Also attached image for better clarification.

[image]

Comment: The latter command would push to the public docker repository. I am sure you don't have the right to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The following command `gcloud docker -- push redis` is not pulling the image from the google container registry. This is pulling the [redis image from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/), which is the default docker registry.

By default, if an image is not tagged with the registry url, docker pulls/pushes the image from dockerhub.

For pushing an image to GCR, you need to tag it with the GCR repository url. This is explicitly documented in [Pushing and Pulling Images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling):

> Before you can push a Docker image to any private registry, you need to tag the image with a registry name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to push to the public [redis repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) instead of your own private repo. When running `gcloud pull`, you are most likely downloading the official redis container from hub.docker.com where most official containers are hosted. Push uses the same logic to determine what repo you are talking about. It's failing to push because you are not authorized to push to the offical redis repository.